# Looking for any alternate state management tool for react other then redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am looking for a state management tool for react other then redux. please help

Comment: Have you tried context API ?

Comment: please use google or any search engines for this type of question - you can check [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/redux-react-alternatives-c1733793a339#:~:text=Conclusion,connect%20many%20different%20platforms%20respectively.) for redux alternative

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=redux+alternatives
Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving your state into the top-level component and pass the state down using props. Or you could also use another library similar to redux called [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview)